# Creating interactive map

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I've a question, how can I create the same same map like [here](http://mogily.pl/gorlice/plan-cmentarza).

What to use, and how to do a map with elements on it which are showing when I'm zooming on it?
Also, how can I prepare database to store also images?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Though it is a very general question but let me answer you in brief. First let's simplify the notion of a map.

I would assume a map is **a block** made of many child blocks and each child is divided to 4 blocks. Look at the following:

[image]

So the number of images that are required to make a map equals the number of squared in the image which is calculated based on this correlation:

[image]

where "n" is the degree of zoom in your map.

In order to translate the idea to the web language, the following steps have to be taken:

1- Identify the degree of zoom.
2- Save the files in a database table, indicate their parent ids and positions. here is a sample of how the data table should look like for "1" degree of zoom:

[image]

3- On the client side, employ **Ajax** and **HTML Canvas** and use **javascript** event handler to track users' mouse movements.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This map seems to be made with google maps api. Examples of other javascript mapping libraries are openlayers, leaflet, mapbox-gl.

These libraries all have support for zooming and panning. mapbox and google have data services that you can use to put (background) data in your map. If you have your own data, you need to convert it to some format for the mapping library to use. The specifics on how to do this depend very much on the kind of data, the type of map usage, the chosen mapping library, the dynamics of the data etc. etc.